# how to prove that a sequence consisting of real numbers only converges to one limit

Tags: real-analysis

I know the proof is supposed to be written by contradiction with the assumption that it converges to more than a one limit. however I do not know how to go about doing that.

Comment: A sequence can't converge to more than one limit. It either converges to one limit or it diverges. If you search for "proving divergence" on this site or on google you will see some great examples that I think may help you.

Comment: The essential fact is that the distance between two real numbers is $\geq \delta > 0$.

Comment: How can the $n$th term get arbitrary close to two different numbers?  Assume it does, and you'll quickly arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Do you know how to write an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are two limits for your sequence, $\{a_{n}\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. If $L_{1}\neq L_{2}$ (suppose $L_{2}>L_{1}$), take $\epsilon=\frac{L_{2}-L_{1}}{2}>0$, then by definition of limite there exist $n_{1}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|L_{1}-a_{n}|<\epsilon$ for all $n>n_{1}$ AND also by definition of limite there exist $n_{2}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{n}-L_{2}|<\epsilon$ for all $n>n_{2}$.

But, if $n>\max\{n_{1},n_{2}\}$ then $a_{n}$ can't be near of both:

if this happend $2\epsilon=L_{2}-L_{1}=|L_{2}-L_{1}|\leq||L_{2}-a_{n}|+|a_{n}-L_{1}|<2\epsilon$, that is $\epsilon<\epsilon$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Assume it has two limits $L$ and $M$.  Use the $\epsilon -N$ definition which says there is some $N$ after which all the numbers are within $\epsilon$ of the limit.  Now if $\epsilon =\frac 12|L-M|$....